# How do I use a method in another class, do be used in another method?

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm trying to use a method that is in another class, to be used in another class's method (this other class is not the driver). It's a bit complicated but I'll try to recreate my situation simplified:

```
public class Class1 { 
private String component;
void Class1(String component) {
       this.component = component
}
String get() {
       return component;
}}
```

This is the second class

```
public class Class2<Class1> {
ArrayList<Class1> arraylistofClass = new ArrayList<Class1>();
void addandPrint(Class1 class1) {
arraylistofClass.add(class1);
System.out.println(class1.get());
}}
```

So essentially I am trying to add an array list of the first class, populate it, then print out what the second class's array list was populated with. However, I can not access the .get() method of class1 in my code, when I try to run the addandPrint method in my driver. I'm sorry if this is a bit confusing but does anyone know if there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think you need to use generics for `Class2`

Comment: Compressing the code into as small of a space as possible does not make it run faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in

```
public class Class2<Class1> {
```

Here you declare a *type parameter* called `Class1`. The name of this parameter shadows the actual class name, which means that when you type `Class1` inside the definition of `Class2`, it doesn't mean "the class I just defined in the other file", but "whichever type the user of `Class2` chooses to put between the `<>`". And there is no guarantee that that type will even have a `get()` method.

There doesn't seem to be any reason at all why you want `Class2` to have a type parameter in the first place, so the **quick fix** would be to change it to

```
public class Class2 {
```

and leave everything else unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you created a class,thencreated some elements of the class(generics), added them in an arraylist and then you are having trouble accessing the methods.
Correct me if I'm wrong.

Well, if that's the case then follow the below code.

```
class Student{
   private String name;
   private int id;

   Student(String name, id){
      this.name = name;
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName(){ return name;}
   public int getId(){ return id;}

   public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }
   public void intId(int id){ this.id = id;}

   public String someMethod(){
      return "Mr. " + name + "(" + id + ")";
   }
} // end class
```

Second Class

```
class Class2{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
      //Adding elements to the List
      students.add(new Student("abc", 1));
      students.add(new Student("def", 2));
      students.add(new Student("geh", 3));
      students.add(new Student("ijk", 4));

      for(Student student : students)
         System.out.println(student.someMethod()); //You can access any public and protected method like this
   }
}
```

Comment: You've got the right idea of what I'm trying to do, but is there any way for me to create instances of the first class in the main method instead of creating the instances inside the second class, while still being able to access the methods inside of the second class?

Comment: See the first class is called a model class and there is no point of making an instance in the first class as it is just  like a blueprint of the type sutdent which is used to store student information. The actual work is done in the second class that is adding information and creating a list of objects. You have to create an instance where you want to access/modify/store objects of class Student(first class). If you still have doubts, post more code in your question and I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an access modifier on your `get` method. By default, this makes it package-private (accessible to all classes in the same package). In your case, you need to make it public:

```java
public String getComponent() {
    return component;
}
```

Also, that's not how you define a constructor in Java. You're defining a method with a return type of `void` that happens to have the same name as the class. [You can see the docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: I've tried to make the get method public in my original code, but to no avail.